# How can I calculate this correctly?

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$string = "[Rank 10] Carlos_Regenz [Rank 9] Anthony_Woods [Rank 9] Habib_Merkel [Rank 9] Garry_Brian"
```

And i need to calculate it (from my example it will be):

```
$rank10 = 1;
$rank9 = 3;
```

If I'm not mistaken this is done through `preg_replace`, but I haven't studied it yet.

Another example:

```
$string = "[Rank 10] Carlos_Regenz [Rank 10] Anthony_Woods [Rank 10] Habib_Merkel [Rank 9] Garry_Brian"
```

Output:

```
$rank10 = 3;
$rank9 = 1;
```

Comment: You should clarify what your input is. Is that supposed to be an array of strings? One long string? Ideally use actual PHP code or var_dump/print_r output. And assigning the results to individual variables probably isn't a good idea. You should use an array with ranks as keys.

Comment: Okey, I edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the post before you edited it, So the string can be split by new line right?

If a square bracket (]) is not a valid name, you can split it there and then another split on the word "Rank" and then trim the remaining string to get the number. Then create an array with a check like this:

```
if (isset(array[RANK_NUMBER])){
    array[RANK_NUMBER] += 1;
}else{
    array[RANK_NUMBER] = 1;
}
```

Code can be shorter using regex but might be slower than doing splits and trim

Answer (score 0):

Find any sequence of digits before a close bracket

```
preg_match_all('/\d+\]/', $input, $ranks);
```

Then count how many of each number were found.

```
$ranks = array_count_values(reset($ranks));
```